# How to build parent-child datagridviews if the child is a TableValuedFunction that requires a parameter?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I'm trying to do linked parent-child datagridview controls in a Winforms app bound to SQL Server.

VS can generate working code if I model a few tables in the DataSet and define the Relations between them. However, my understanding is that the DataSet is loaded at startup in that case(using the generated code).

The next challenge is that I need a parent table as before, but the child table is bound to a Table Valued Function. It's not clear how to link the two controls. Presumably I need to call Fill on the child control on some row selection event change? In other words it's code that has to written on the control, not something that can be built in the gui automatically from the DataSet?

It's essentially a lazy-load scenario, where each selection in the parent reloads the data in the child.